# Finding the max number in JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement, max, java.util.scanner

```
        if(max.hasNextInt())
        { 
            num = max.nextInt();
        }
```

How do I find the max number when using a scanner and sentinel values? my method only displays the last integer inputted. 
I've been at this for hours and have put my pride to sleep, I need help....please help..........

Comment: You could also consider to use [Math.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,%20int)) to get the maximum.

Comment: @user3185727 you shouldn't edit out the details after it's been answered.

Answer (score 2):

You condition that tests if the current number is higher than the current maximum is in the wrong place.

Change

```
    if(max.hasNextInt())
    { 
        num = max.nextInt();
    }

    else
    {
        if(num > totmax)
        {
            totmax = num;
        }
        ...
```

to

```
    if(max.hasNextInt())
    { 
        num = max.nextInt();
        if(num > totmax)
        {
            totmax = num;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are checking if the number is bigger then the current maximum in the `else` clause. Which won't be entered when the user inputted a number (because than it entered the `if` clause).